# Why 'NaN' and 'Undefined' are not reserved keywords in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, keyword

We can do:

```
NaN = 'foo'
```

as well as

```
undefined = 'foo'
```

Why are they not reserved keywords?

1. I think it should be implemented in order to be sure that when we are looking for a `number`, it is a `number` :)
2. If we should use `IsNaN()` or `typeof`, why are `NaN` or `undefined` needed?

Comment: Regarding your second point: They are not needed, that's why `undefined` and `NaN` **are not** keywords.

Comment: @Baszz - by that logic it should be possible to overwrite the value of `true`, `false`, `null`, etc., but it isn't.

Comment: @nnnnnn true, false, null can't be overwritten.

Comment: @BhavyaDhiman - Yes, that's what I said. (Though it appears the comment I was replying to has been deleted.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

> NaN is a property of the global object.
>
> The initial value of NaN is Not-A-Number — the same as the value of
>   Number.NaN. In modern browsers, NaN is a non-configurable,
>   non-writable property. Even when this is not the case, avoid
>   overriding it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

> undefined is a property of the global object, i.e. it is a variable in global scope.
>
> The initial value of undefined is the primitive value undefined.

Answer (score 9):

I cannot tell you *why*, but `undefined` and `NaN` are actually **properties** of the global object:

> #### [15.1.1   Value Properties of the Global Object](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1)
>
> **15.1.1.1   NaN**
>   The value of **NaN** is **NaN** ([see 8.5](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5)). This property has the attributes { [[Writable]]: **false**, [[Enumerable]]: **false**, [[Configurable]]: **false** }.
>   (...)
>   **15.1.1.3   undefined**
>   The value of **`undefined`** is **undefined** ([see 8.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.1)). This property has the attributes { [[Writable]]: **false**, [[Enumerable]]: **false**, [[Configurable]]: **false** }.

There is a difference between the *value* `undefined` (`NaN`) and the corresponding property.

You might notice the `[[Writable]]: false`. I'm not sure whether this new in ES5 (and might not be adapted by all browsers), but in newer browsers (tested in Firefox 6), assigning a new value to `undefined` has no effect:

```
[12:28:15.090] < undefined = "foo"
[12:28:15.093] > "foo"
[12:28:19.882] < undefined
[12:28:19.883] > undefined
```

So although it *seems* you can assign a new value, you actually **cannot**.

---

> Why they are not reserved keywords?

Not sure if there was a specific reason to not make them reserved keywords, but it was decided against it. The language still works. You cannot override these values, so it's fine.

The only way to test whether a number is `NaN`, is to use `isNaN()` anyway.

Comment: @downvoter: Please leave a comment so that I can improve my answer. Thank you!

Comment: You can assign a value to undefined in ECMA 3 but not in ECMA 5 :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm speculating now, but the reason why I think `NaN` and `undefined` are not keywords is because you generally don't assign these values to variables.

```
var x = undefined; // doesn't make sense, use null!
var y = NaN; // You can't do much with this variable!
```

`undefined` basically means `uninitialized`, and if you want to make it clear that the value is unknown you use `null`. So `undefined` usually means not-initialized or the result of JavaScript code gone wrong.

`NaN` Is rarely assigned manually, simply because you can't do much with this value. It is usually the result of a calculation gone wrong. The makers of JavaScript probably didn't want to give this value the visibility of primitive values.

Also, `NaN` is also present in other languages and it isn't used as a keyword there either. For example: In `C#` NaN is represented by `Double.NaN`, since you don't make a distinction between floating point and integer values in JavaScript, I'm guessing that's why they put `NaN` with the Global Identifiers!

I hope this clears things up!

Answer (score 1):

`NaN` is not a keyword, but it is rather a built-in property of the global object, and as such may be replaced (like `undefined`, but unlike the keyword this or the literals `true`, `false`, and `null`).

You can test if a value is NaN with the `isNaN()` function. Moreover `NaN` is defined to be unequal to everything, including itself.

Or in a nutshell you can say that:

`NaN` is the value returned when you try to treat something that is not a number as a number. For instance, the results of 7 times "abc" is not a number. The old form of it is Number.NaN. You can test for not-a-number values with the `isNaN()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Both `NaN` and `undefined` are **values** in JavaScript.

1. `NaN` is of number type. (it denotes "not a valid number").
2. `undefined` is of undefined type. (when there is nothing assigned to a variable, JavaScript assigned `undefined` particular in `var` declaration).

And also both are read-only values(property) of global window object.

So that's why **JavaScript cannot make values as a reserved word**.

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that it is possible to use those words as object keys:

```
messages = {
  NaN: 'that was not a number',
  undefined: 'that was not initialized',
  default: 'that was something' // not in the original question but is valid syntax
};
console.log (messages.NaN);
```

While it would be possible to use `{ 'NaN': 'that was not a number' }` and `console.log(messages['NaN'])`, leaving as many words as possible unreserved could make your code easier to read.