# How to check if a scope variable is undefined in AngularJS template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

How to check if a scope variable is *undefined*?

This does not work:

```
<p ng-show="foo == undefined">Show this if $scope.foo == undefined</p>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Ah, I didn't think about the fact that you wouldn't have access to the "typeof" keyword in your template markup.  Sorry about that.  I've removed my close vote.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Here is the cleanest way to do this:

```
<p ng-show="{{foo === undefined}}">Show this if $scope.foo === undefined</p>
```

No need to create a helper function in the controller!

Comment: This is not reactive. Meaning when foo changes, ng-show does not change accordingly.

Comment: curly braces should not be used with ng-show as it expression only. Curly braces are used for evaluating an expression inside an otherwise string text

Comment: I receive `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at ..`.

Answer (score 28):

Using `undefined` to make a decision is usually a sign of bad design in Javascript. You might consider doing something else.

However, to answer your question: I think the best way of doing so would be adding a helper function.

```
$scope.isUndefined = function (thing) {
    return (typeof thing === "undefined");
}
```

and in the template

```
<div ng-show="isUndefined(foo)"></div>
```

Comment: or you can use angular's helper function, angular.isUndefined(object) / angular.isDefined(object)

Comment: I would argue that not being able to handle an object with an undefined property is bad design front end code.

Answer (score 9):

Corrected:

HTML

```
  <p ng-show="getFooUndef(foo)">Show this if $scope.foo === undefined</p>
```

JS

```
$scope.foo = undefined;

$scope.getFooUndef = function(foo){
    return ( typeof foo === 'undefined' );
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oakley349/vtcff0w5/1/

Comment: You're right, didn't think of it that way.  Editing answer

Comment: This is not correct either, since `undefined` is not a JavaScript keyword (it's a variable).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173773/why-nan-and-undefined-are-not-reserved-keywords-in-javascript

Comment: It is better practice to do `return (foo === undefined);` than `return (typeof foo === 'undefined');`.

Comment: @Oakley  Please note === operator itself check value and type as well. So you don't need to do complex code using typeof operator

Answer (score 6):

Posting new answer since Angular behavior has changed. Checking equality with undefined now works in angular expressions, at least as of 1.5, as the following code works:

```
ng-if="foo !== undefined"
```

When this ng-if evaluates to true, deleting the percentages property off the appropriate scope and calling $digest removes the element from the document, as you would expect.

Answer (score 4):

If `foo` is **not a boolean variable** then this would work (i.e. you want to show this when that variable has some data):

`<p ng-show="!foo">Show this if $scope.foo is undefined</p>`

And vise-versa:

`<p ng-show="foo">Show this if $scope.foo is defined</p>`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Angular 1, I would recommend using Angular's built-in method:

angular.isDefined(value);

reference : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isDefined

Answer (score 1):

You can use the double pipe operation to check if the value is undefined the after statement:

```
<div ng-show="foo || false">
    Show this if foo is defined!
</div>
<div ng-show="boo || true">
    Show this if boo is undefined!
</div>
```

[Check JSFiddle for demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mahdi_fathalla/66mfuyza/10/)

For technical explanation for the double pipe, I prefer to take a look on this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34707750/6225126

Comment: Um, no, that's not an equivalent to check whether it is actually undefined. Your example will fail if `boo` variable is `0`, `null`, `false`, or just an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

As @impulsgraw wrote. You need to check for undefined after the pipes:

```
<div ng-show="foo || undefined">
    Show this if foo is defined!
</div>
<div ng-show="boo || !undefined">
    Show this if boo is undefined!
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mjfz2q9h/11/

Answer (score -1):

try this
angular.isUndefined(value);

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isUndefined

Answer (score -3):

`<p ng-show="angular.isUndefined(foo)">Show this if $scope.foo === undefined</p>`