# Why isn't undefined an invalid left hand assignment?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Either my google-fu is failing or no one has asked this question (doubtful), but: Why isn't this throwing an `Invalid left-hand assignment` error?

```
❯ node
Welcome to Node.js v18.17.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> undefined = 'asdf'
'asdf'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has historical reasons. Unlike `null` and `true` and `false`, `undefined` is not actually a keyword but a global variable with no value. (It was always a bad idea in my mind but now it's too late.)

Trying to change this variable *will* fail if you enable [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode?retiredLocale=de), although the error will be a bit different, complaining it can't set a read-only property.

Otherwise, it will appear to work and the assignment itself will evaluate to the new value (that is always the case with any assignment regardless of what it actually does), but the global variable `undefined` won't be changed because it's set as a read-only property on the global object.

Nobody stops you from declaring a new local variable (or class or function) with that name however - which is quite an evil and confusing thing to do though, but I guess you can annoy your coworkers with it after you already handed in your resignation...? (Don't do that.) But that's why we have linters - any reasonable linter will not let you use footguns like this even when the language itself allows it.

---

This is also the reason why you would sometimes see old code that looks like this:

```js
(function (undefined) {
  // ...
})();
```

(Sometimes with more arguments passed to the [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE?retiredLocale=de), but the last argument would be missing.) The idea here is that the argument named `undefined` is declared but no value is passed in the function call at the end, so its value will always be undefined. This protects against some other code overwriting the global `undefined` with something else. (One could also simply have put `var undefined;` at the start of the function, but this is shorter and less "noisy" inside the function body if an IIFE is desired anyway for scope separation.)

Comment: Isn't node.js always run in strict mode?

Comment: No it isn't. And even though there is a `--use-strict` argument, this applies only to stdin and `-e`, not to script files and REPL.

Comment: This is also the reason why you sometimes find `typeof foo === "undefined"` instead of just `foo === undefined`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález The other reason is that people also used to try and check for _undeclared_ variables, which does work with `typeof` (the only place where you can use an undeclared identifier without crashing), and then people incorrectly got taught even in courses "to check whether a variable is `undefined`, you need to use `typeof`, otherwise you will crash". There should be zero reason to use this technique now though - if you want to know whether a global variable is defined, use `if ('variableName' in globalThis)`, and if you need to check for a _local_ variable... then you messed up.

Comment: @Teemu As stated, normally, no, but Node and browsers (etc) _are_ always in strict mode when using ES Modules, eg `node index.mjs` or `<script type="module" src="">`. No need for `"use strict";` there.

Comment: "historical reasons"... have people tried to fix this already? seems like low-hanging fruit, and it seems like the only downside is it would break (surface?) malicious code as you described.

Comment: Oh, I guess these are reasons why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173773/why-nan-and-undefined-are-not-reserved-keywords-in-javascript

Answer (score 4):

According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined), `undefined` is a totally legal variable name when used in a local scope:

```js
(function write() {
  let undefined = "Some string value";
  console.log(undefined);
})()
```

But its value cannot be overwritten in the global scope:

```js
let undefined = "Some string value";
console.log(undefined);
```

**Edit:** more accurately it is a valid **identifier** name, so it can also be used as the name of a function!

```js
(function write() {
  function undefined() {
    console.log("Some string value");
  }
  undefined()
})()
```